# Create a bootable USB installer from a external hard disk partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb, partitioning

I have a 1TB external disk. I want to have a usb installer for both windows and ubuntu.

But I do not have any USB. So I partitioned the external drive with 8GB, 8GB and the rest for data. The 8GB partitions are both "Healthy (Primary Partition)".

I started the Windows USB and DVD tool and selected an image but when I try to select a USB device it says: `No compatible USB devices detected`.

I also tried the Universal USB Installer 1.9.5.7 for Ubuntu but the same problem, no selectable drive.

So what could I be doing wrong? Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: You write "I want to have a usb installer for both windows and ubuntu.  But I do not have any USB." <-- what are you talking about

Comment: Also, you mention "mac mini" in another comment. But it's not like that has no USB ports. "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini#Fourth_generation_(USB-C)". It'd be quite dfficult to find a computer with no USB ports

Comment: And if you have no USB stick then what are you doing trying to create a bootable USB installer, whatever that means anyway. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this.

1. If the current OS on your system is bootable and when loaded you can see the External HDD you can simply copy a Windows or Ubuntu installation disk to any partition on your External Drive and run either of them to install one of the OSs. After installing one OS you can then install a boot manager and install the other OS.
2. If your PC does not have a bootable OS and you need to boot from the External HDD to install an OS then you have to make one of the partitions on the EHDD bootable.

Have a look here for further details.

Adding a boot partition to my external hard drive

[Adding a boot partition to my external hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/688955/adding-a-boot-partition-to-my-external-hard-drive)

Again after you have installed the new OS you can install a boot manager and install the other OS.

Here are some useful boot tools

http://www.boot-us.com/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

====

Comment: I have a maverick on a macmini. How do I know if its a bootable OS?